# Best approach for hosting multiple applications on AWS with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have several applications (nodejs & angular) that I am moving to AWS. I have set up my clients using CloudFront. However, I'm not quite sure how to go about setting up my backends on AWS.

Let's say I have five domains a.com, b.com, d.com, d.com, and e.com

These are small applications so I don't necessarily want to have five different EC2 instances. Currently they are all running on a single EC2 instance on different ports.

I'm not sure how to set up https:// routing to all these instances. For example I need to make requests from my clients to https://a.com, https://b.com and so on.

What is the recommended approach to accomplish a set up like this?

Comment: Is your EC2 instance a windows server or linux server?

Comment: my instance is linux

Comment: I'm not sure is this the best approach, but according to your requirement of not using ELB you can try this approach. You can add host information in vhost file of you ec2 instance and point your domain on particular ip and different port no.s. Refer to the link given [here](http://brianshim.com/webtricks/host-multiple-sites-amazon-ec2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have a lot of apps (sites) and you want to provide the good level of automation, scaling and auto-remediation for them in the cloud while doing CI/CD, then I would highly recommend to use Kubernetes. Recently Amazon released their 'Kubernetes as a service' which is called AWS EKS. We already started to use it on production and it works for us very good for the same case as you described. We run 3 Kubernetes workers on EKS, so AWS abstracts the maintenance of Kubernetes control plane from us while our CI / CD (Helm, Gitlab, Jenkins, Ansible) benefits from Kubernetes declarative configs and Kubernetes downtimeless deployments. For more details you may check an article that I published recently after evaluating AWS EKS for production workloads: https://bekitzur.com/blog/amazon-eks/

When running a bunch of sites on AWS EKS, you can tell it to reuse a single load balancer (ALB) for several apps (sites). So the decision to put the site under the balancer of the other site or not in AWS EKS only depends on your site reliability concerns. If you are OK that accidentally breaking the balancer (or certificate on it) can affect more than one site, then you can reuse the same ALB many sites. ALB scales up pretty well in terms of throughput and requests count so running few sites under the same ALB should not become a balancer performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scenario, you can setup Amazon ECS to run multiple applications. With the newly introduced [Amazon Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) for Amazon ECS and EKS, it allows to run containers without having to manage servers or clusters.

Note: You need to dockerize your applications to run as containers.

You can setup Application Load Balancer(ALB) and CloudFront to configure SSL and to terminate SSL connections. CloudFront can be used outside the ALB to cache static content at edge locations.

Comment: would I need a load balancer for each application? Let's say I have 20 different applications.

Comment: Not necessary, you can setup even one ALB with routing configuration on path or dns based to different target groups. For ECS this can be done at Service ALB attachment.

Answer (score 0):

One can have different domain on AWS provided these are small applications.
Just simply have different directory root mention the virtual host eg :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@a.com
    DocumentRoot /home/a/public/
    ServerName a.com
    ServerAlias www.a.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Similarly you can have for b,c d and e domain.

Also you can install ssl for each 5 domains.
All you have to do is install SSL and configure the virtual host eg :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@a.com
  DocumentRoot /home/a/public/
  ServerName a.com
  ServerAlias www.a.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/".crt file name"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/"key file name"
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/"IntermediateCA_.crt file"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want always redirect http://a.com to https://a.com
Need to rewrite the rule as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
#Redirect everything to https:
Redirect permanent / https://a.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://a.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Similarly for other 4 domains.

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with docker then use ECS to host 5 apps in one ec2 or fargate host 5 apps without ec2.

If you are not familiar with docker then use the method you knew.

Create 5 target groups, one for each of your app with different ports, then create an application load balancer (ALB).

- In ALB you can specify which host (e.g app1.com) to the target group 1 and app2.com to the second target group.
- You can also add 5 different ssl certs to one ALB to severve all your apps.

Finally, point your dns records to the same ALB

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be using ALB, however out of the box EKS uses ELB when you use LoadBalancer in the service spec and provisions a separate ELB for each k8s service.

You can specify a different ingress controller, either ALB ([AWS ALB ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller)) or something cross platform like nginx ([nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)) but at least for ALB it's a special interest group and not functionality AWS support natively in EKS.

Answer (score -1):

I would go ahead by creating ELB (elastic load balancer) for each application listening on different ports and then configure each ELB with DNS name in Route 53.

Comment: this is what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to have 20 load balancers when the traffic to each app is small.